# Fourier transform of a signal sequence?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Desparately, I am trying to calculate the Fourier transform of the following signal sequence. What can it be?

$$f(x)=\left(\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x\ln(T)\sin[\pi\ln(x)/\ln(T)]}\right)^2$$

while $x > 0$.

Comment: I would be sort of surprised if there is an analytic formula for the Fourier transform of this contrived function.

Comment: @LubošMotl is there a specific reason why you would say there wont be any?

Comment: @al-Hwarizmi "most" functions haven't a nice analytic Fourier transform. Is there a reason to hope that in  this particular case there is one?

Comment: @Andrew one would be more than welcome to show rigorousely that there does not exist an analytic Fourier Transform for this equation. Either there is one or there is not, *hope*, as you raise, should be on either or.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring domain restrictions (e.g., $\log(x), x<0$), as I am not even sure this function is defined for all $x>0$, I think this is as good as you are going to get:

$$
f(x) = (g(x))^2 \Rightarrow F(\omega) = G(\omega)\ast G(\omega)
$$

$$
g(x) = \alpha \cdot \operatorname{sinc}(x) \cdot h(x)
$$

$$
h(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sin \left( \pi \log(x) / \log(T) \right) }
$$

$$
G(\omega) = \alpha \cdot \operatorname{rect}(\omega) \ast H(\omega)
$$

Good luck finding $H(\omega)$. In all likelihood you will have to do an asymptotic approximation. It doesn't look highly oscillatory, so nothing jumps out.

Comment: Thanks; this looks a step forward but the challenge of an answer to the question is obviousely exactly at what you have pointed out as $H(\omega)$. A complete and detailed solution to this problem is extremely important for me.

Comment: You first need to make sure that this function is well-defined, as you have two terms in the denominator that can equal zero, one of which does so every $2\pi$. Second, you need to make sure that a Fourier transform exists, since the $1/\sin$ term can lead to infinite values.